# Can my follower hold the same legendary item as my character?

Tags: diablo-iii

I know that your character cannot hold two of the same legendary items (such as two Won Khim Lau fistweapons), but what about my follower? If I'm using a Maximus, can I give a second Maximus to my Enchantress, or will it tell me I can't?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can.  I just tested this by buying and equipping 2 cheap uniques.  Even though I could not equip both on my character, I was able to equip one and give the other to my follower.

I also tried to give my follower 2 of the same unique ring.  He was only able to equip one of them, so followers also cannot bypass the unique equipped requirement.

Comment: Can the follower equip both?

Comment: @Sorean nope.  I updated my answer.